# How to load cloned content as a var

Tags: jquery

Trying to load content into a div, then on click load the previous content that was in the div again.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var mainClone = null;
   $('.project').click(function(e){
      var link = $(this).attr('rel');
      event.preventDefault();
      var mainClone = $('#main').clone();
      $('#main').load(link);
   });      

  $('.back').click(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#main').load('mainClone *');
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me nuts!

On a side note, is this a good solution to my problem?
I'm trying to achieve something similar to the work section on: http://www.revolver-studio.com/ 
You click a thumb and it goes into more info then you click back to go to the thumbs again.
ANY help would be really appreciated.
Thanks guys!

Comment: I took a look at the source code on the site and some CSS. It turns out that it's not what you think. there's an empty div that has the same height and width as the visible scroll-container. They load the data into that container based on the link clicked. They simply use display:none; to hide the container injunction with $.remove(); to achieve this effect. They don't ever save the state.

Comment: Passing the even as `e` then referecing it as `event` probably wont work

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you so much for giving me that idea. Can't believe I didn't think of it. Works like a charm. Even when I got everything working, bringing back the cloned html screwed up a filter I had going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems.

First is the second use of `var mainClone` within project click handler. This is declaring a new variable named `mainClone` and is not the same as the original one you declared. The new one only has scope within the function it is declared in, so the original more global one will never change.

Next problem us use of `load()` when you want to replvce the html with the stored html. It is both inappropriate for what you want to do and the argument is simply a string which is invalid.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var mainClone = null;
   $('.project').click(function(e){
      var link = $(this).attr('rel');
      event.preventDefault();
      /*var mainClone = $('#main').clone();*/ 
      mainClone = $('#main').html();// now will update var declared above and only get the html within the element
      $('#main').load(link);
   });      

  $('.back').click(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();
  if( mainClone ){ // make sure it's not null still
    $('#main').html( mainClone);
  }
  });
});
```

Overall this code will still be a little weak but it is not intention of SO to build an app for you. It should get you started

Comment: Thank you! Still learning jQuery and you have provided me with a great lesson. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to save the divs and hide them. In this example, they're "cached" and don't require additional loads (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project[rel]').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('rel');
        var $target = $('#main .pane[rel=' + href + ']');
        if ($target.length == 0) {
            $target = $('<div class="pane" rel="' + href + '">Loading...</div>').appendTo('#main').hide().load(href);
        }
        $('#main .pane').hide();
        $target.show()
        return false;
    });
});​
```

You will probably want to use the `$.ajax()` method instead of `$.fn.load()` because it will allow you to handle HTTP/connection errors gracefully.

It's also generally not a good idea to use the `rel=""` attribute in that way since it has a specific purpose with a list of expected values http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_a_rel.asp

With HTML5, I would recommend using the new data-attributes, e.g. `data-href=""`. John Resig has an excellent article on this http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main').load('mainClone *');
```

This is incorrect syntax and function usage. You're not calling any external file so you need to use any DOM manipulator like `html()` or `appendTo`, but not `load()`

```
$('#main').html(mainClone);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92h75/1/